# Migration from SSAS Multidimensional cube to Tabular model

Tags: ssas, cube, ssas-tabular

I hope you are doing well.

I'm working on a migration from an on premise ssas multidimensionnal cube to an azure analysis services tabular model.

Is there a way , a method or a tool to do it quickly and efficiently?

It's a large cube and it will take time to develop it from scratch with tabular model.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3):

SSAS Multi Dimensional (MD) and Tabular are fundamentally different technologies, there is no quick method of converting one to the other, you will have to rebuild the model from scratch, and the measures etc.

Be aware that some of the things MD models are good at, like calculating up and down hierarchies, Tabular really struggles with. If the cube is fundamentally sound and has good performance, and you want to move it into the cloud service, use a VM in Azure, with SQL Server on it, it may work out cheaper that Azure AS, per month.

Comment: I had to redo the tabular model